# SQL state imssp server 2100 parameter error PDO

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, pdo

I am getting:

> Error.  SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 65536. SQL
> Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameterr in a LINQ to SQL query. I
> connected to mssql server with php. i have installed "Microsoft
> Drivers for PHP for SQL Server" and added some lines in extension part
> of php.ini.

I am using Windows 7 and IIS 7.5. I checked results from `phpnifo()`. Loaded Configuration File C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini.

Where am I making mistakes? I want to make a request to SQL Server.

```
    include('connect.php');
    try
    {
        
        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO [deneme].[dbo].[deneme_tablosu] ([ad], [soyad]) VALUES (?,?)");
        
        $query->bindParam(':ad',$ad, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':soyad',$soyad,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        
        $ad=$_POST["ad"];
        $soyad=$_POST["soyad"];
        $query->execute();

        echo "successful";
    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {   
        echo 'Error'.$e->getMessage();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use named parameters or placeholders, not both. The following example, based on the code in the question, is a possible solution:

Using placeholders:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
try
{
    
    $query = $conn->prepare("
       INSERT INTO [deneme].[dbo].[deneme_tablosu] ([ad], [soyad]) 
       VALUES (?, ?)
    ");
    $ad    = $_POST["ad"];
    $soyad = $_POST["soyad"];
    $query->bindParam(1, $ad, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(2, $soyad, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($query->execute()) {
        echo "successful";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }   
}

catch(Exception $e)
{   
    echo 'Error'.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Using named parameters:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
try
{
    
    $query = $conn->prepare("
       INSERT INTO [deneme].[dbo].[deneme_tablosu] ([ad], [soyad]) 
       VALUES (:ad, :soyad )
    ");
    $ad    = $_POST["ad"];
    $soyad = $_POST["soyad"];
    $query->bindParam(':ad', $ad, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':soyad', $soyad, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($query->execute()) {
        echo "successful";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }   
}

catch(Exception $e)
{   
    echo 'Error'.$e->getMessage();
    
}
```

Comment: you caught it! Thank you